# Echo sessions middleware not saving

Tags: session, go, gorilla, go-echo

I am trying to use the [sessions middleware](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/session) for the [echo web framework](https://echo.labstack.com/). The middleware is essentially just a wrapper around [gorilla/sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions) tailored to work with echo.

I have basically just copied the example given in the documentation and extended it slightly.

```golang
e := echo.New()
e.Use(session.Middleware(sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("Secret"))))

// Add the name "Steve" to the session
e.GET("/login", func(c echo.Context) error {
        sess, err := session.Get("session", c)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        sess.Options = &sessions.Options{
            Path:     "/",
            MaxAge:   0,
            HttpOnly: false,
            Secure:   true,
        }
        sess.Values["name"] = "Steve"
        sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())
        return c.NoContent(http.StatusOK)
    })

    // Reply with the name saved in the session
    e.GET("/whoami", func(c echo.Context) error {
        sess, err := session.Get("session", c)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, sess.Values["name"])
    })
```

I expect to first visit `/login` to save the name to the session, and then visit `/whoami` and receive the name `"Steve"`.

`/login` returns `StatusOK` as expected, but `/whoami` always returns `null`. Why isn't the name being saved to the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by settings `session.Option.Secure = true`.

I am testing locally and not using `HTTPS` so the cookie is not being set.